# Adding a floating point number to the looping index in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I am trying to add a floating point number to the looping points. My loop is non sequential.

```
j=9.46 
for i in 8.0 7.5 7.0 6.5 ;do
    $i = $i + $j |bc

    echo '$i'
```

i also tried

```
ans=$(( x + y ))
k=$[$i+$j]
```

i have to add the constant to the looping index and use it in a command later in the script. I am able to echo the output using |bc but can't use it in the script as a variable later.

Comment: You wrote "I am able to echo the output using |bc but can't use it in the script as a variable later.", but the script shown in the question is incomplete and contains errors. Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the complete code that does "echo the output using `|bc`". Then it will be easy to store the result in a variable. Hint: post your code at http://shellcheck.net to find errors

Comment: Include the error messages that get printed when you run your code. Don't make us have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

The `bash` shell (contrary to ksh93, zsh or yash), can't do floating points in its arithmetic evaluations, but you can always invoke a tool that does. `bc` is good for arbitrary precision calculation, but here `awk` may be a better tool as it's good with working with arrays, arithmetic and loops:

```
awk -v increment=9.46 -- '
  BEGIN {
   for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) print ARGV[i] + increment
  }' 8.0 7.5 7.0 6.5
```

Would output:

```
17.46
16.96
16.46
15.96
```

Note that `awk` outputs floating points numbers with 6 digit precision by default. Add a `-o OFMT=%.10g` for instance for 10 digit precision (internal calculations will generally be done using C `double` type numbers with usually 64 bits of precision).

Answer (score 0):

In the loop try something like:

```
i1=$(echo " $i + $j" |bc)
echo "$i1"
```

First you should not have spaces around `=`
Second single quotes will prevent shell from interpret the content of variable

Comment: You can also use a heredoc `i1=$(bc <<< "$i + $j")`

Comment: @rr0ss0rr, technically, that's rather called a *herestring*. Depending on the version of `bash`, that will use a temp file or a pipe to feed the contents to the command.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification